# Sending Email w/ Attachment AND only Present Email Clients as option

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm attempting to allow for users to send an email with attachments. This being the closest I got, allows for email clients to be chosen but no attachments. I'm assuming I have the types wrong, and shouldn't be using two. Can't seem to get this to work with both attachments and ONLY email clients to appear in dialog.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
i.setType("application/image");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"Jenna@JennaRocks.org"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT HERE");
i.setType("message/rfc822");

// Photos
String path = prefs.getString("image_one", "");
String path2 = prefs.getString("image_two", "");

ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
imageUris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + path)); // Add your image URIs here
imageUris.add(Uri.parse("file://" + path2)); // Add your image URIs here

i.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of text");

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send email..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(GrievanceFormActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```